# Redirect all requests that DO NOT match a set of RegExes to a different subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain pointed at the webroot of my site, and all o the content on that subdomain is handled by a single PHP page. However, because the subdomain is set up as an alias of the www host and not its own folder, you can also access all of the content on the www domain through this subdomain.

This creates a duplicate content scenario, so I'd like to 301 all traffic to pages NOT handled by the subdomain (everything except the homepage and URLs matching one regex) back to the WWW domain. Here's what I tried:

```
# subdomain page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mysite\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub-([a-z\-]+)/([a-z]+)$ subdomain.php?var=$1&page=$2 [L]

# REDIRECT OTHER REQUESTS BACK TO MAIN SITE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mysite\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub-([a-z\-]+)/([a-z]+)-page$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Not only does this code seem to forward ALL traffic (even the pages that should be kept on subdomain) to the www domain, it seems to un-do the canonical URLs and redirect to a URL with bare GET string (ex. subdomain.mysite.org/sub-1/sub2 gets redirected to www.mysite.org/subdomain.php?var=1&page=sub2)

Anyone know why this is happening and how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you get to your redirect rule, the first rule would have already been applied. So you just need to exclude the target of the first rule:

Try:

```
# REDIRECT OTHER REQUESTS BACK TO MAIN SITE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mysite\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This works great for my internal pages, but adding 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$ [NC]

and

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mysite\.org [NC]
 RewriteRule ^$ subdomain.php?page=index [L]

doesn't seem to work for the subdomain's homepage. It's still redirected to www no matter what I do.